# Start metro app (camera) from WPF application

Tags: .net, wpf, camera, microsoft-metro

I have a ordinary .net 4 WPF application which is supposed to be run on a Windows 8.1 tablet. From this application I would like to start the native Metro camera app, if it is available.

I´ve tried looking for answers, but it seems to require a Windows app to start metro apps.

So is it even possible?

Thank you :)

Answer (score 6):

Have a look at this article: http://winaero.com/blog/exclusive-how-to-start-a-modern-app-from-desktop-without-going-to-the-metro-start-screen/

Basically, you need to run:

`explorer shell:AppsFolder\Microsoft.MoCamera_cw5n1h2txyewy!Microsoft.Camera`

e.g. Use:

```
Process.Start("explorer", @"shell:AppsFolder\Microsoft.MoCamera_cw5n1h2txyewy!Microsoft.Camera");
```

I'm not sure that this will be super reliable or future-proof, but it works on all of the Windows 8.1 machines that I have tried it on!

Answer (score 2):

There's a way to open metro apps (Windows Store apps) from desktop, but the app is required to have a protocol associated with it. Goto Control Panel > Default Programs > Associate protocol... (something like that) and check for protocols associated with each app..

Unfortunately, the default camera app doesn't seem to have any protocol.

The .exe file for camera app lies in **C:\Windows\Camera** folder for Windows 8.1 (I am not sure if it was there in Windows 8) but double-clicking that doesn't do anything. I guess only Windows knows how to start it.

Here's how you can test starting apps by protocol: Open IE or any other browser and type: *ms-windows-store:/* in the address bar.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
In windows 8.1 there is a c:\Windows\Camera folder, but not in Windows 8. Starting the Camera.exe will crash as you say, and the event viewer doesent really provide any valuable information.

I am looking for a solution which doesent require any preconfiguration of the computer. But I guess it aint possible since the camera app doesent have a protocol associated with it.

Thanks alot for your contribution though!